# Will Google+ Photos automatically migrate to the new Google Photos?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos, google-photos, auto-upload

Today in their Keynote at Google I/O, Google announced their new [Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) app that does most of what they did with my photos when they auto-uploaded to Google+, but with a few and some significant additions and differences.

My devices are currently uploading to the new Google Photos but my question is, **since my pictures are/were already being auto-uploaded to Google+ Auto-Backup already, will those show up in Photos as well?** Or am I starting out fresh?

Answer (score 5):

I just installed the app and I have access to all my G+ photos, plus the ones I have in Google Drive and a few scattered ones that were only on my phone.

Comment: Ah! It seems I do as well, although they weren't there earlier when I was poking around after installing. They do connect, thank you @Al E.!

Comment: It did take a little while to build the local database.